# Open New Activity by id on Listview Item Click

Tags: java, android, listview

My ListView is opening and everything is ok. I don´t know how to pass params from onPostExecute() to onItemClick() to open a new activity (SingleItem.java) by id.
Nothing that I´ve tried has worked.

ListItems.java

```
public class ListItems extends Activity {

private ListView listV;
TextView estado, cidade, noItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_items);

    listV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV);

    estado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Estado);
    cidade = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Cidade);
    noItem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noItem);

    estado.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("state"));     
    cidade.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("city"));

    Task task = new Task();
    task.execute();

    listV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleItem.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

public class Task extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>{

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListItems.this);

    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Listing Items...");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                Task.this.cancel(true);
            }
        });
    };

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        String url = "http://myip/webviews/jsonlistItems.php";

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error connecting to database " + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(ListItems.this, "Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void v){

        try {
            JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                jsonObject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                // output
                String item_id = jsonObject.getString("item_id");

                String item_name = jsonObject.getString("item_name");
                String item_color = jsonObject.getString("item_color");
                String city = jsonObject.getString("city");
                String statee = jsonObject.getString("state");

                if(estado.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(statee) && 
                        cidade.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(city)){

                    String[] values = new String[] {item_name, item_color};

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListItems.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

                    listV.setAdapter(adapter);
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    noItem.setText("No Item to show");
                }
            }
            this.progressDialog.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
    }

}


public class ItemById{

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_events, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

SingleItem.java

```
public class SingleItem extends Activity {

TextView item_name, item_color;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_singleitem);

    item_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    item_color = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_color);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.event, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

How to pass params from onPostExecute() to onItemClick() to open a new activity (SingleItem.java) by id?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your code correctly. The way it's coded right now, the list only contains two elements? The name and the color of one of the elements you read from your json stream? My guess is, that this isn't intentional but a bug and it should show every element that matches your criteria (the if statement)?

Comment: I have state.java and city,java activities. User types state then state is shown in city.java, where user types city. State and city are shown in ListItems.java. According to state and city, a query is perfomed in the DB to show the items from that city.
These items will be listed in a ListView by name, for example. Then when I click on each item in the ListView, I want to show the rest of the attributes of the corresponding item in another activity (SingleItem.java)

Comment: Yes but your adapter only takes one item and creates the Adapter from the name and the color instead of using all items. AFAIK the code would show two list items, one with the name and the second one with the color of the first item that matches the state and city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends what your SingleItem Activity is supposed to show when it's opened.
If you only need the name of the selected item then you simply retrieve the item name in the onItemClick method and pass it as parameter to SingleItem:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleItem.class);
    String name = adapter.getItem(position);
    intent.putExtra("yourItem", name);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In order for this to work the adapter needs to be a variable in the Activity:

```
public class ListItems extends Activity {
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
```

and this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListItems.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
```

becomes this:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListItems.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
```

If you need more information in the SingleItem Activity than just the name of the item you'd have to create an Item class to hold that information:

```
public static class Item implements Serializable {
    String mName;
    String mColor;
    // more data

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return mName;
    }
}
```

your onItemClick becomes:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleItem.class);
    Item item = adapter.getItem(position);
    intent.putExtra("yourItem", name);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Your adapter would be:

```
ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter;
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(ListItems.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemArray);
```

Of course you'd need to create the itemArray when parsing the json stream.

The activity could easily read the selected item from the intent like so:

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("yourItem");
```

Comment: That´s what I thought but "adapter cannot be resolved" inside onItemClick

Comment: Yes you need to define it as variable in the activity, see my changed answer

Comment: Great Emanuel ! How do I hide the Items (like id) in the listview? I´d like to keep just the name of the item in the listview and show all the others attributes just in SingleItem.java.
If I setAdapter(adapter); any item inside values will be shown.

Comment: By now I can get just one item in the ListView from the DB query, even if there is more than one in the same city. This updated answer will help me to get all the register in the DB or should be better to do mysql commands?

Comment: Your question was "how to pass params from onPostExecute() to onItemClick() to open a new activity (SingleItem.java) by id". That's exactly what my answer is addressing. Click on an item and the id or the whole item is passed into your Activity and you do whatever you need to do there.

Comment: If you have more questions on top of what you already asked, consider posting a new question. Just be aware that others might not want to answer your questions if you don't mark them as correct or give them at least a thumbs up.

Comment: I'm not allowed to give a thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

The adapter looks like it's populated only by each attribute of your JSON object (one row for item_name, one row for item_color). If this is what you want the naturally you won't get item_id because it's not there.

If you want each row to correspond to each of your JSON objects then you should modify your adapter.

First make your own class like so

```
class Wrap{
    String itemId, itemName, city, statee;
}
```

And then create your own Adapter class that extends `ArrayAdapter<Wrap>`.

This way every time a row is clicked, you can get the Wrap object which contains everything, including id. Then you can pass these values to your next Activity.